# Group of polynomials with real coefficients under adition - antiderivative that passes through $(0,0)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be the group of all polynomials with real coefficients under addition.
For each $f$ in $G$, let **$\int f$ denote the antiderivative of $f$ that passes
through the point $(0, 0)$**. Show that the mapping $f \rightarrow \int f$ from $G$ to $G$ is a homomorphism. What is the kernel of this mapping? Is this mapping a homomorphism if $\int f$ denotes the antiderivative of f that passes
through $(0, 1)$?

My question here is what does the bolded sentence mean?  Does it mean the $n$-th antiderivative of $f$ such that $(x,y) = (0,0)$ is a solution after $n$ consecutive antiderivatives?

Comment: For any polynomial $f$, there exist a unique antiderivative $g$ such that $g(0)=0$. Take that antiderivative as $\int f$.

Answer (score 1):

The text you've highlighted isn't very clearly phrased. It just means that $\int f$ is the unique polynomial $h$ whose derivative $h'$ is equal to $f$ and is such that $h(0) = 0$ (so the graph of $h$ "passes through the point" $(0, 0)$). The final part of the question is asking what happens if you change your mind and require $h(0) = 1$ instead. (The requirement that $h$ be an antiderivative of $f$, i.e., that $h' = f$, does not determine the constant term of $h$.)

Answer (score 1):

The antiderivative of a polynomial is a family of polynomials one degree higher than the original, the family being parametrized by the additive constant of integration. The given "initial condition", that the polynomial should pass through $(0,a)$, fixes the constant to be $a$.

Example: the antiderivative of $x+2$ is $x^2 + 2x + c$. We must have $c = 0$ in order for $0$ to be a root of this polynomial, so the homomorphism maps $x+2$ to $x^2 + 2x$. It would map to $x^2 + 2x + 1$ if you required the curve to pass through $(0,1)$ instead.